# Tensorflow: kurtosis of a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, kurtosis

Is it possible to calculate the kurtosis of a tensor, instead of `tf.reduce_std` something like `tf.reduce_kurt`?

Comment: I don't know if there's a tf function for it, but you could compute the 4th central moment by: computing the mean, then subtracting that, then raising the tensor to the 4th power, then taking the mean again. Then, to get the kurtosis you'd divide by the variance squared.